# Abi encode / decode using strings instead of bytes

Tags: solidity, abi

For some reason beyond my control, I need to store encoded data in a `string` variable.

I know `abi.encode` and `abi.decode` usually work on `bytes memory` but I also believe that `string memory` can be casted to `bytes memory`.

Here is an example contract I use to debug in remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test
{
    function encode(uint256 a, string calldata b) external pure returns(string memory)
    {
        return string(abi.encode(a, b));
    }
    function decode(string calldata a) external pure returns(uint256, string memory)
    {
        return abi.decode(bytes(a), (uint256, string));
    }
}
```

It works great with some values. For example `encode(42, "test")` returns

```
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000*\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004test\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

which can then be decoded back to `42, "test"`.

However, for some values, such as `255, "test"`, then I get a revert when trying to decode the encoded string.

Any idea how to solve that ? Is their no other way then to use `bytes` instead of `string` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think I would focus on the testing methodology.

The contract looks okay to me.

I fiddled with it a little to test the original two functions and ended up with something that seems to work. It works for both examples, e.g. `255, "test"`.

I didn't find a case where it doesn't work. Admittedly, did not test very much.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test
{
    function encode(uint a, string memory b) internal pure returns(string memory)
    {
        return string(abi.encode(a, b));
    }
    function decode(string memory a) internal pure returns(uint, string memory)
    {
        return abi.decode(bytes(a), (uint, string));
    }

    function test(uint a, string calldata b) external pure returns(uint, string memory) {
        string memory encoded = encode(a, b);
        return decode(encoded);
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it confirms that there is a possible string representation, but when I try to compute it offchain and pass it to a smart contract I can't manage to make it work. My usecase is trying to decode something that was passed as an argument, stored somewhere in a string and by a contract I don't control, and then read by my contract

Comment: Change the two internal functions to public so the client can use them. The advantage here is you are ensuring all clients and all languages will always have a way to convert that matches what the contract expects. Use the contract's pure functions to do offchain computations, and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: They are external, and I tried ... calling the encode sometimes cause `revert` (for example with 255, "test")